# Run an another cmd

Tags: c#, console-application

I make a C# console program and I want to execute some batch treatments in an other cosole.

So, I have the main program which write in the console and at a certain moment I want to execute batch treatment in an other one.

I know how execute batch treatment in the main console but I want to do that in an other one, that is my question.

How can I make that ?

EDIT :
I use a StreaWriter to write in the console like that :

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

using (StreamWriter writer = process.StandardInput)
{
    if (writer.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        // commands...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Process.Start:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "yourcommandhere");
```

Comment: I can't do that :s
(see my edit)